# How to prove: if $x\in [-3,4]$ then $5\leq |x-3|+|x+2| \leq 7$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

So far I have that if $-3 \leq x \leq 4$ then we have that:

$-6 \leq x -3 \leq 1$  and $-1 \leq x+2 \leq 6$

So $|x-3| \leq 6$ and $|x+2| \leq 6$ but I'm not sure how to continue the proof.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%28%28x-3%29%5E2%29%2Csqrt%28%28x%2B2%29%5E2%29 helps

Answer (score 2):

For the first inequality note that $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ so $5=|3-x+x+2|\leq |x-3|+|x+2|$. If $x\geq 3$ you have $|x-3|+|x+2|=2x-1\leq 7$ because $x\leq 4$. If $-2\leq x\leq 3$ you have $|x-3|+|x+2|=-x+3+x+2=5\leq 7$. If $x\leq -2$ you have $|x-3|+|x+2|=-x+3-x-2=-2x+1\leq 7$ because $x\geq -3$.